# Connecting to TFS over VPN

Tags: vpn

At work I can connect to the Team Foundation Server (TFS) from Visual Studio and do all the source control etc. that I need to. However, when working from home and connected to work via VPN I cannot connect to TFS.

I tried pinging the TFS server from home (over VPN) and from work and in both cases it can see the server. I also tried entering IP address instead of the DNS name and the same story: works from the work computer but not the one at home.

Any idea why this is or how it could be resolved?

Comment: Error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the route between the two.  Are the routing rules different between the two subnets.  Are there firewall rules that are only letting traffic through from your dev net but not from your VPN net?

Comment: I did a tracert between the two and they go through completely different routes to get to TFS.

Comment: I would guess there is a firewall or routing rule that does not allow the traffic run nmap or some other port scan to see what ports you see on the remote host.  Then talk to a network admin about the differences you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue. It ended up being a setting within IIS and it was set to an old IP address with in Web Management Service. Double check that also.